# is there a way to avoid the Dirac Delta in the fourier transform?

Tags: fourier-analysis

I would like to compute the fourier transform of H1[t], as you can see the output of mathematica gives the the dirac delta:

```
n3p = {-1, 0, 0};

ep = {{1, 0, 0}, {0, -1, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}; 

h[t] = hp[t]*ep

hp[t] = h0*Cos[Wgw*t];

H1[t] = Integrate[h[t], {t, t - L3/c, t}].n3p.n3p

H1[ω] = 
FourierTransform[H1[t], t, ω, FourierParameters -> {-1, 1}]
```

This is the output :

> (I h0 DiracDelta[-Wgw + ω])/(2 Wgw) - (  I E^((I L3 Wgw)/c) h0
>   DiracDelta[-Wgw + ω])/(2 Wgw) - (  I h0 DiracDelta[Wgw + ω])/(2 Wgw) +
>   (  I E^(-((I L3 Wgw)/c)) h0 DiracDelta[Wgw + ω])/(2 Wgw)

Is there a way to avoid the DiracDelta? And to keep it equal to 1?

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by "keep it equal to 1"?

Comment: I mean that I do not want to have the dirac delta in my FT output, there should be a link with the argument of your FT ..if the argument if >1 then you should not have the dirac delta in your output..but i am not able to figure out how to do that..

Comment: I really do not get your point... Sure, there might be ways to express the output differently (without `DiracDelta`) but that won't change the fact that the Fourier transform of `H1` is a distribution and not a function...

Comment: so, maybe I should change my question, do you know how I can plot it? I obtain always 0!

Comment: Are you saying that the result is incorrect?  What result would you expect then?  It seems to me that there's a mathematical misunderstanding here (i.e.  the question isn't really Mathematica-related).

Comment: @Martina The Fourier transform of `H1` is [distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)) and not a function. That's why it cannot be plotted. (People often say nonesense like the Dirac delta is a function that vanishes everywhere away from `0` but its integral over every interval containing `0` is `1`. Which simply means: It is not a function; it is something different.)

Comment: A Dirac $\delta$ cannot be plotted in the same sense as functions can, but it can be illustrated in various ways, e.g. by drawing a vertical line at the appropriate position.  You could use the `HalfLine` graphics primitive for this.

Comment: @Szabolcs: It would be useful for the OP to look in Wiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function as a first reading.

Comment: One can superpose a dirac (represented by a segment of line) with a classical function, but it's worth mentionning that the Y axis has not the same graduation for the two representations. For example if the X axis values are in seconds and the Y axis values are in volts *for the function*, then the heigh of the dirac is in volts X seconds.

Comment: ... and of course the X axis is the same for the two representations.

Answer (score 2):

One can replace the Dirac delta function by one of its expressions in the form of a limit, and then take a finite value of the function, for example

```
n3p = {-1, 0, 0};

ep = {{1, 0, 0}, {0, -1, 0}, {0, 0, 0}};

h[t] = hp[t]*ep;

hp[t] = h0*Cos[Wgw*t];

H1[t] = Integrate[h[t], {t, t - L3/c, t}].n3p.n3p;
g[x_] := Exp[-(x/a)^2]/a/Sqrt[Pi]
f = FourierTransform[H1[t], t, \[Omega], 
    FourierParameters -> {-1, 1}] /. {DiracDelta -> g} // FullSimplify
```

Here we obtain

```
(E^(-((Wgw^2 + \[Omega]^2)/
  a^2)) h0 (Sin[(L3 Wgw)/c - (2 I Wgw \[Omega])/a^2] + 
   I Sinh[(2 Wgw \[Omega])/a^2]))/(a Sqrt[\[Pi]] Wgw)
```

To display, we use this function

```
p[W_, h_, L_, c0_, a0_] := 
 Plot[Re[f /. {Wgw -> W, h0 -> h, L3 -> L, c -> c0, 
     a -> a0}], {\[Omega], -3 W/2, 3*W/2}, PlotRange -> All, 
  AxesLabel -> {"\[Omega]", "H1(\[Omega])"}, WorkingPrecision -> 100]
```

Finally, we construct a distribution

```
p[1, 1, 1, 1, 1/100]
```

[image: fig1]

Comment: Your math is not traditional math. Can you kindly give a reference to base your answer? TIA.

Comment: @user64494 Do you mean the representation of the Dirac delta function as a limit?

Comment: It is not so simple and primitive: if you look in Wiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function as a first reading, you will understand that this limit is not a usual limit, but a limit in $\mathcal{D} '$ topology which is not implemented in Mathematica.

Comment: But this does not prevent us from using this representation to visualize the Fourier image containing the delta function.

Comment: I repeat your visualization is  profanation of the Dirac delta function.

Comment: This is not a profanity, it's just an example. You can specify your example. Perhaps it will be better.